# Django redirect preserving subpath

Tags: python, django

In my `urls.py` I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^django-admin/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin/', permanent=True)),
]
```

So if I go to `localhost:8000/django-admin/` it successfully redirects me to `localhost:8000/admin/`, and if I go to `localhost:8000/django-admin/my-app/` it also redirects me to `localhost:8000/admin/`.

How could I make `localhost:8000/django-admin/my-app/` go to `localhost:8000/admin/my-app/`? And the same for every possible subpath e.g. `localhost:8000/django-admin/my-app/my-view`, `localhost:8000/django-admin/another-app/`, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView) something like this should work, you can capture groups from the path and pass them to the url

> The given URL may contain dictionary-style string formatting, which will be interpolated against the parameters captured in the URL. Because keyword interpolation is always done (even if no arguments are passed in), any "%" characters in the URL must be written as "%%" so that Python will convert them to a single percent sign on output.

```
url(r'^django-admin/(?P<rest>.*)', RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin/%(rest)s', permanent=True)
```

This website is particularly useful for figuring out how the built-in class-based views work http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.base/RedirectView/#get_redirect_url